# php warning why ? unable to solve it

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting a warning message which I don't understand why and unable to resolve, (see below)

```
Warning: Supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /detail.php on line 34
```

Here is my code:

```
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
 $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM <tablename> WHERE id=" . $_GET["serviceName"];
 // Loop the recordset $rs
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))   **(line 34) here ***
{
 echo $row['ID']."<br />";
       echo $row['serviceName']."<br />";
     // Close the database connection
mysql_close();
?>

</dl>
<p><a href="li.php">Return to the list</a></p>
  </body>

</html>
```

thanks in advance, I am not getting any of the data on this webpage either,thanks...singhy

Comment: You executing query and than assigning query to `$strSQL` variable. Take it above the `mysql_query` statement.

Comment: why `$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);` is before setting the variable ?

Comment: **Waring:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: What is the data type of `id`?

Comment: hi abhik,rikesh and mark for quick response, thanks it worked ok, I can not seem to get the data displayed, I am using echo "<dt>Name:</dt><dd>" . $row["serviceType"] . " " . $row["serviceName"] . "</dd>"; thanks...singhy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is failing -  you need to wrap quotes around strings in MySQL:

> $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM gu_service_cat WHERE id = '" .
>   $_GET["serviceName"] . "'";

plus, the $rs should be BELOW the $strSQL...

Comment: hi farcie thanks yes it worked but I can not get the data to display I am using echo "<dt>Name:</dt><dd>" . $row["serviceType"] . " " . $row["serviceName"] . "</dd>"; thanks in advance...singhy

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like this

```
 $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM gu_service_cat WHERE id=" . $_GET["serviceName"];
 $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
```

Because before setting value to the variable you are using it in the query. This is why it is throwing the error.

Comment: hi there tried it, no joy thanks for the quick response.